# Azure app service, currently restricting access to various test systems via IP address. Is there a better way to restrict access?

Tags: azure-web-app-service, azure-appservice

We have a number of test/uat app services and websites running on app services.  We currently restrict access via IP address by adding the IP address to the firewall.

This worked fine when it was mostly developers with static IP addresses but now we have suppliers and customers accessing the UAT systems from various places including home.  It's a pain to maintain the IP addresses.

Ideally, I would like to be able to setup users in Azure and give them access to the various test system via this user.

Is there anyway to do something similar or is there a better approach.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Azure App Registrations with a client secret and then use the client credentials flow to obtain access. This is probably the easiest way.

Comment: Thank you, how would this work if I had several websites in Azure?  Do I register each as an app and then give a domain user access to that website?